Some sources (including Wikipedia) appear to use a different sign for the inner product of two bivectors compared to other sources. Which is correct?
For this question I'm specifically assuming one of the usual Euclidean Clifford algebras, like $G_4$ or $G_5$, etc...
(By Euclidean I mean that the quadratic form is not only positive definite but is represented in matrix form by the identity matrix)
Here in this Wikipedia entry the scalar part of the geometric product of two bivectors has the same sign as the inner product, which implies that the inner product of two identical nonzero bivectors would always be negative, which is wrong as far as I'm aware.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector#Product_of_two_bivectors
Note that the geometric product of two bivectors is introduced as $$AB = A \cdot B + A\times B + A \wedge B$$ $\tag1$
instead of
$$AB = -A \cdot B + A\times B + A \wedge B$$ $\tag2$
I've asked ChatGPT about this, and it told me that the inner product $A \cdot B$ is defined as the grade zero part of $-\frac{1}{2}(AB+BA)$ where $A$ and $B$ are bivectors, which to me indicates that (2) is the correct formula, not (1)
Under this definition of the inner product of bivectors, the inner product of two identical nonzero bivectors will always be positive.
The version of the inner product provided by ChatGPT which agrees with (2) makes more sense to me, since I would expect the inner product of a nonzero bivector with itself to be positive.
Question
Is (2) the correct formula for the geometric product of two bivectors, where $A\times B = \frac{1}{2}(AB-BA)$?

Neither is incorrect. There are two main conventions for the interior product. One stems from the scalar product $\langle AB\rangle$ and the other from $\langle\widetilde AB\rangle$ with $\widetilde A$ reversal, hence the extra minus sign when $A$ is a bivector.
Both conventions are common.

(2) makes more sense to me, since I would expect the inner product of a nonzero bivector with itself to be positive.

That doesn't mean much more than "I like it because I like". This kind of reasoning also utterly fails in mixed signature where for a nonzero bivector you can get any sign, incuding zero. There are good reasons to like one convention or the other, and not really any reason one is more "correct" than the other.
